# Trouble generating a depth map (black screen)

Tags: opengl, shadow-mapping

I am having trouble generating a depth map for my scene. I tried to figure out this issue a 2 weeks ago and got nowhere after days of trying to fix it, so I took a break and tried to tackle it again today. I'm still stuck and with no ideas.

Here's the main code:

```
#Sets up the depth FBO and the texture that will be used to render to a quad
const unsigned int d_width = 1024, d_height = 1024;

    unsigned int depthFBO;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &depthFBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depthFBO);

    unsigned int depthMap;
    glGenTextures(1, &depthMap);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthMap);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, d_width, d_height, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthMap, 0);
    glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
    glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);

    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        std::cout << "Incomplete stuff!" << std::endl;

    glBindBuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    glm::vec3 lightPos(-2.0f, 4.0f, -1.0f);
```

Rendering loop:

```
/* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);

        #render scene from the light's perspective
        float near_plane = 1.0f, far_plane = 8.0f;
        glm::mat4 lightProj = glm::ortho(-10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f, near_plane, far_plane);
        glm::mat4 lightView = glm::lookAt(lightPos, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        glm::mat4 lightSpaceMat = lightProj * lightView;

        depthShader.use();
        depthS.setUniformMat4("lightSpaceMat", lightSpaceMat);
        glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        depthS.setUniformMat4("model", model);

        glViewport(0, 0, d_width, d_height);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depthFBO);
        glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        
        #render everything else
        planeVAO.bind();
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));
        depthS.setUniformMat4("model", model);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

        cubeVAO.bind();
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, -2.0f));
        model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.6f));
        depthS.setUniformMat4("model", model);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(2.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f));
        depthS.setUniformMat4("model", model);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

        #render to the quad now which is supposed to display the depth map
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        glViewport(0, 0, scr_width, scr_height);
        glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        
        quadVAO.bind();
        quadShader.use();
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE15);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthMap);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Here are the shaders:

depth shaders:

```
#vertex
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

uniform mat4 lightSpaceMat;
uniform mat4 model;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = lightSpaceMat * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}

#fragment
#version 330 core

void main()
{
    gl_FragDepth = gl_FragCoord.z;
}
```

visual quad shaders:

```
#vertex
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTex;

out vec2 TexCoords;

void main()
{
    TexCoords = aTex;
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}

#fragment
#version 330 core

out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoords;

uniform sampler2D depthMap;

void main()
{
    float depthValue = texture(depthMap, TexCoords).r;
    FragColor = vec4(vec3(depthValue), 1.0);
}
```

Anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong? I have tried debugging in every way I could think of and have made no progress.

edit: full source.cpp code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <glm.hpp>
#include <gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include "Shader.h" 
#include "Textures.h"
#include "Camera.h"
#include "Context.h"
#include "Renderer.h"
#include "DataDefs.h"
#include "Renderer.h"
#include "StaticDataDefs.h"
#include "VertexBuffer.h"
#include "Context.h"
#include "Model.h"

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <tuple>
#include <array>

#include "imgui/imgui.h"
#include "imgui/imgui_impl_glfw.h"
#include "imgui/imgui_impl_opengl3.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <map>

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"

float planeVertices[] = {
    // positions            // normals         // texcoords
     25.0f, -0.5f,  25.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  25.0f,  0.0f,
    -25.0f, -0.5f,  25.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f,  0.0f,
    -25.0f, -0.5f, -25.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 25.0f,

     25.0f, -0.5f,  25.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  25.0f,  0.0f,
    -25.0f, -0.5f, -25.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 25.0f,
     25.0f, -0.5f, -25.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  25.0f, 10.0f
};

const unsigned int scr_width = 800;
const unsigned int scr_height = 600;

float quadVertices[] = {
    // positions        // texture Coords
    -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
};

int main(void)
{
    //Setup all openGL stuff
    setProject init;
    GLFWwindow* window = init.returnWindow();

    Camera camera; 
    camera.setInputs(window, camera);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    Shader normal;
    normal.setUpShader("Resources/Shaders/lightObject.vs", "Resources/Shaders/lightObject.fs");
    Shader depthS;
    depthS.setUpShader("Resources/Shaders/depthS.vs", "Resources/Shaders/depthS.fs");
    Shader depthR;
    depthR.setUpShader("Resources/Shaders/depthR.vs", "Resources/Shaders/depthR.fs");

    Context va;
    VertexBuffer vb(vert3d.size() * sizeof(Def3), vert3d.data(), 's', "type3a", GL_FALSE, GL_FLOAT);
    va.addBuffer(vb, "VBO");
    GLCall(va.setVBOAttribs());

    Context va2;
    VertexBuffer vb2(sizeof(quadVertices), &quadVertices[0], 's', "type2a", GL_FALSE, GL_FLOAT);
    va2.addBuffer(vb2, "VBO");
    GLCall(va2.setVBOAttribs());
    
    Context plane;
    VertexBuffer planevb(sizeof(planeVertices), &planeVertices[0], 's', "type3a", GL_FALSE, GL_FLOAT);
    plane.addBuffer(planevb, "VBO");
    GLCall(plane.setVBOAttribs());
   
    depthR.use();
    depthR.setInt("depthMap", 15);

    const unsigned int d_width = 1024, d_height = 1024;

    unsigned int depthFBO;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &depthFBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depthFBO);

    unsigned int depthMap;
    glGenTextures(1, &depthMap);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE15);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthMap);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, d_width, d_height, 0, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthMap, 0);
    glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);
    glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);

    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        std::cout << "Incomplete stuff!" << std::endl;

    glBindBuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    glm::vec3 lightPos(2.0f, 4.0f, 1.0f);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
     
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);

        texo.textureBinder(0);

        //set up scene, draw objects, etc.

        camera.processInput(window);
        camera.calcDelta();

        float fov = camera.return_fov();

        float near_plane = 1.0f, far_plane = 8.0f;
        glm::mat4 lightProj = glm::ortho(-10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f, near_plane, far_plane);
        glm::mat4 lightView = glm::lookAt(lightPos, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        glm::mat4 lightSpaceMat = lightProj * lightView;

        depthS.use();
        depthS.setUniformMat4("lightSpaceMat", lightSpaceMat);
        glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        depthS.setUniformMat4("model", model);
      
        glViewport(0, 0, d_width, d_height);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depthFBO);
        glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        depthS.use();

        plane.bind();
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));
        depthS.setUniformMat4("model", model);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

        va.bind();
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, -2.0f));
        model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.6f));
        depthS.setUniformMat4("model", model);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(2.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f));
        depthS.setUniformMat4("model", model);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        glViewport(0, 0, scr_width, scr_height);
        glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        
        va2.bind();
        depthR.use();
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE15);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthMap);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        
        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

(the "VA" VAO holds the data for the cubes and "VAO2" for the quad)

https://github.com/julkothegu/p_1_test

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I cant comment yet.

I havent done shadow mapping in openGL yet, however, I cannot see that you are setting your `uniform sampler2D depthMap`.  It should be set like:
`glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(PROGRAM_ID, "depthMap"), 15);`

Its being set to 15 because of this code:
`glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE15);
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthMap)`
In above code you are saying your depthMap texture is at index 15.

**Edit:**
Okay I gave it a try(I am also following the learOpengl.com) and this is my render. Please note I am not doing a double pass .  I am just basically changing my perspective projection to ortho and I got the following result:

[image]

This is my render with perspective:
[image]

Therefore, I would strongly recommend you to first do a normal render and then try the shadows.

Comment: Hi. I set the uniform to that location earlier in the program, I just skipped over much of the setting up code. Everything to do with settings uniforms, VAOs, VBOs, and all other basic stuff isn't the problem here (unfortunately).

Comment: Okay, So now I have to ask what is the problem? I.e what are you seeing? Are you seeing anything on the screen? Does your scene render properly and just not the shadows?

Comment: Nothing seems to be rendering to the screen. It's just black. I'm pretty sure it's not an issue with the framebuffer since it doesn't trigger an incomplete error, and I can't see anything wrong with the shaders. I haven't had anything to go on from for weeks so I was hoping someone could see something wrong with my methodology/usage of openGL/literally anything else.

Comment: I haven't added any shadows yet btw. The only thing I'm trying to do atm is to display the depth of the scene's objects for visualization purposes (something like this: https://learnopengl.com/img/advanced-lighting/shadow_mapping_depth_map.png) Seems like even that is too much for me though.

Comment: I would suggest that you should first render your normal scene.  All we are trying to do with shadows is - put the camera where the light is and look towards the scene you are trying to render.
I can help you with debugging this if you provide the full source code.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I can successfully render my scene without shadow mapping as in this picture: https://gyazo.com/50a0071f08840dfbbd80b3f8bc4d907d (no textures, no lighting, very simple). However, when I try to follow any tutorial and render just the shadow map the screen will remain black. I can post my entire source.cpp code since the rest of my program are classes for shaders, model loading, vbos/vaos, etc. Should be self-explanatory though.

Comment: Hey Julk, I would be able help you if you put your code on the github where I can simply fork it and build it(hopefully).  I am guessing you are not building your depth texture right. If you can render your scene from the camera, there should be no reason you cant do it from the position of light.  Actually there is no camera or light, they are just some "abstract labels" we are giving to the transform matrices. You can call your camera a "light" and its valid.

Comment: I just added the link to the rep to the question and here: https://github.com/julkothegu/p_1_test. Hopefully it isn't too messy. By the way, thank you so much for taking the time to look at this. Being stuck on this for so long makes just quitting very tempting.